# NSPredicate issue with NSObjects IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I have an NSObject:

```
@interface ContactAlphaB : NSObject

+ (ContactAlphaB *)contactWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName username:(NSString *)username
 linkAvatar:(NSString *)linkAvatar registerType:(NSString *)registerType
email:(NSString *)email mobile:(NSString *)mobile;

@end
```

I had save all informations in this object.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *linkAvatar;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *registerType;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *stremail;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *strmobile;
```

And I had show in tableView

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.sectionIndexTitles;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.sectionIndexTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionIndexTitle = self.sectionIndexTitles[section];
    return [self.alphabetizedDictionary[sectionIndexTitle] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CellListsFriend *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellListsFriend" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    ContactAlphaB *contact = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblNameFriend.text = contact.fullName;    
    // Rounded Rect for cell image
    cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderWidth=2;
    cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imgAvatarFriends.frame.size.width/2];
    [cell.imgAvatarFriends.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    return cell;
}

- (void)setContacts:(NSArray *)contacts {
    self.alphabetizedDictionary = [CGLAlphabetizer alphabetizedDictionaryFromObjects:contacts usingKeyPath:@"lastName"];
    self.sectionIndexTitles = [CGLAlphabetizer indexTitlesFromAlphabetizedDictionary:self.alphabetizedDictionary];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (ContactAlphaB *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *sectionIndexTitle = self.sectionIndexTitles[indexPath.section];
    return self.alphabetizedDictionary[sectionIndexTitle][indexPath.row];
}
```

With this code, I can show all myfriend lists in tableView.

And now, I want to do search function (search my friend).

So, I'm using `NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", searchString];` to work this function.

But, I cannot use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` in NSObject to search.

How to I can do search function.

Please help me!

*****************Edited:

```
NSArray *arr = [FriendList MR_findAll];
    if (arr.count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
            FriendList *friendList = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
            [delegate.arrFriendListsAdded addObject:friendList.username];
            ContactAlphaB *contact = [ContactAlphaB contactWithFirstName:friendList.firstName
                                                                lastName:friendList.lastName
                                                                username:friendList.username                                                            
                                                              linkAvatar:friendList.avatar
                                                            registerType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", friendList.registerType]
                                                                   email:friendList.email
                                                                  mobile:friendList.phoneNumber
                                      ];

            [_mucontacts addObject:contact];

        }
    }
```

_mucontacts is NSMutableArray.

When I log this array:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x4e48050>(
<ContactAlphaB: 0x4f55b90>,
<ContactAlphaB: 0x13e8dc0>,
<ContactAlphaB: 0x4f2bd30>,
<ContactAlphaB: 0x4e6a490>
)
```

It is save object. When Search, I want to search lastname.

So, When I search lastname it is get empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
  NSString *searchString = @"your last name here";
  NSPredicate *lastname = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.lastname contains[cd] %@", searchString];
  NSArray *filteredArray = [mucontacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:lastname];
```

Comment: this is NSArray type data of you contact object

Comment: So,I have to create NSArray keyArray and In my cellForRowAtIndexPath.
I have to add data "fullName" to keyArray.

Comment: After that, I will use [keyArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

Comment: but there is an easy and efficient  way to do it

Comment: please try to understand my example

Comment: if you cant inform me

Comment: in this line ContactAlphaB *contact = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: it is an Object:
- (ContactAlphaB *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: this 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate' method can only be implement into 'NSArray'

Comment: Yes! This is my problem.

Comment: but your NSObject does not have any array, so you can't implement NSPredicate

Comment: How to I can search in Object ContactAlphaB get data to an NSArray

Comment: if you have many/ a few of contact instance of "ContactAlphaB" class only then you need to implement filter by NSPredicate

Comment: you may store "ContactAlphaB" instances into an Array, then you may apply filter

Comment: I had added some object to my Contact.

Edited my code